# Error mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, macos

I'm completely new to MySQL and phpmyadmin. I was trying to add a password to my database/phpmyadmin but then I got this error:

> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I'm using XAMPP on a MacBook Air. I've gone through couple of YouTube videos but they're on windows, and the XAMPP looks very different from mine.

I will continue looking for help but I am not winning currently.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. You might find similar errors and possible solution over on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com). [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42941127/1820861) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11096045/1820861) provide possible solutions found on StackOverflow. Could you possibly [edit] your question and add details (the commands) you actually performed? It might help in finding the root cause. Thanks.

Comment: "using password: NO" -> no password was provided to the server. So the problem must be on the phpMyAdmin configuration side ...